# Factors affecting Kp (pressure constant)

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

Initially, I found that $K_\mathrm{p}$ depends only on temperature; but later I found that it depends on pressure of $\ce{CO2}$ gas in case of $\ce{CaCO3 (s, aragonite) → CaO (s) + CO2}$.

How do we know whether it depends upon partial pressure of reactants and products or not? Or, this is a special scenario?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a high gas pressure in the environment the reaction is taking place in, $K_\mathrm{p}$ will shift towards the side of the reaction that has fewer gas molecules, as it is "fighting against" the high pressure, in a way. So in your case, since only one side has gas (the product side) if you increase the pressure of $\ce{CO2}$ or any other gas, the equilibrium will shift towards the reactant side.

Comment: I am sorry. But does this answer the question?

Comment: It seemed to me he was asking if $K_p$ depends on partial pressure of reactants/products, so I was posting about how the equilibrium ($K_p$) shifts due to pressure (which could be partial pressure of a reactant/product, or pressure of some other gas). I hope I didn't misinterpret the question, but I think my post goes some way to answering.

Comment: Sir I want to ask that generally we say that K of a reaction depends only on temperature but in this case it is also depending on pressure of CO2 gas.Why is it so?